# How to update an object in a array using MongoDB Java Driver?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-atlas

Hello I have this document

```
{
  email: "email@gmail.com",
  list: [
    {
      "product": "Car",
      "price": 18
    },
    {
      "product": "Boat",
      "price": 20 
    }
  ]
}
```

I am wondering how to identify the document using the `email` parameter and update a specific object in the `list` parameter by finding the ***product*** with the "Car" parameter and updating the ***price*** to 15 using the MongoDB Java Driver.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by  "identify the document using the email parameter"?. It would be better if you add some explanation about your problem and code you have tried

Comment: @komatiraju032 I am not sure how to approach this using the MongoDB Driver and the email key in the JSON object that I have provided

Comment: specific object means is there any condition?

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to update the nested document of an array field based upon a condition.

**(1) Update using the Positional $ Operator:**

The [positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document, and the array field must appear as part of the query document;i.e., `"list.product": "Car"`. And, secondly only the first matching array element will be updated.

```
db.collection.updateOne( 
  { email: "email@gmail.com", "list.product": "Car" }, 
  { $set: { "list.$.price": 15 } } 
)
```

**(2) Update using the Filtered Positional $[identifier] Operator:**

The [filtered positional operator $[identifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) identifies the array elements that match the `arrayFilters` conditions for an update operation.

Note the condition on the array field is not required when using the `$[identifier]` update operator. And, secondly all the matching array elements (`"product": "Car"`) will be updated.

```
db.collection.updateOne( 
  { email: "email@gmail.com" }, 
  { $set: { "list.$[ele].price": 15 } },
  { arrayFilters: [ { "ele.product": "Car" } ] }
)
```

---

**Update using MongoDB Java Driver:**

***Case 1:***

```
Bson filter = and(eq("email", "email@gmail.com"), eq("list.product", "Car"));
Bson update = set("list.$.price", 15);
UpdateResult result = coll.updateOne(filter, update);
```

***Case 2:***

```
Bson filter = eq("email", "email@gmail.com");
UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions()
                              .arrayFilters(asList(eq("ele.product", "Car")));
Bson update = set("list.$[ele].price", 15);
UpdateResult result = coll.updateOne(filter, update, options);
```

***Reference:*** [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/)

Comment: To complete this great anwser, if you don't want to filter the elements in there array (aka if you want to update all the entries of the array), you should use `Updates.set("list.$[].fieldToSet", newValue)`

Comment: Can you please also tell us how to replace any single object entirely from the list in the example above? Like in your answer you are using $set to update only price of an element in the array of lists. What if we need to replace this object 
```{
      "product": "Car",
      "price": 18
    },```
entirely with new one?

Comment: @jarvo69 You can update more than one field using the `$set` update operator.